# Prolog program to search book by book_title ,by book_author, by book_edition using recursion

Tags: prolog

I am trying, but unable to solve this as I am totally new to Prolog. Anybody can help to solve it?

My Code:

```
firstBook(the_design_of_everyday_things,don_normas,third_edition).
secondBook(elementary_statistics,a_step_by_atep_approach,fourth_edition).
thirdBook(beginning_linux_programming,neil_methew,third_edition).

Find_book:-
    repeat,nl,
    write('Book Lists:'),nl,
    write('1. Human Computer Interaction'),nl,
    write('2. Probability and Statistics'),nl,
    write('3. Operating System'),nl,nl,
    read(Opt),
    {
        Opt = 4,
        write('Not Available'),!
        ;
        selectedchoice(Opt),
        fail
    }.
```

Comment: Find_book is a variable, not a predicate. You also need to change the brackets {}. selectedchoice/1 is not defined. Please describe what the predicate is supposed to do.

Comment: Why "using recursion"? You definitely do not need recursion to query the database. Put your books in a table, **not** in three separate facts. Finally, **do not** use write like this. It serves no purpose. Use variables and let the toplevel print them for you.

Comment: It is helpful that you provided some code. However, additionally need to describe what your code is supposed to do.